# iSeries SQL - Use Previous Record Value in JOIN criteria

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In my example, I am trying to retrieve records from a transaction file based on the previous calendar work date.  The work dates are in a file called CALNDR, the transactions in a file called TRNHST.  The logic would be to use the CURRENT_DATE to set the cursor on CALNDR, then retrieve the previous work date which will be used to join to TRNHST.  This would be simple enough if done in RPG but I am at a loss with SQL.  Thanks, for any input you can provide.

[CALNDR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv3V8.png)

[TRNHST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVK3j.png)

Comment: You can probably use `LAG()`. Please post a few rows of sample data and the expected result of the query.

Comment: I have not been able to get the LAG function to work, likely because I am not coding it correctly.  It will return the current date record but the lag_caldt field is null.  However, if I remove the date selection from the where clause, it shows the previous value as expected.

Comment: select
        CALDT,
        lag(CALDT, 1)
        over(partition by CALN order by CALDT) as lag_caldt,
from
        AMFLIB9.CALNDR CALNDR
where
        CALN = 'MAPICS'
        AND qgpl.fromcymd(CALDT) = CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 1):

This is even more simple with SQL probably.
You may run these statements as is to check.

**LAG function use**

```
WITH 
  CALNDR (CALDT) AS
  (
    VALUES
      CAST ('2022-07-21' AS DATE)
    , CAST ('2022-07-22' AS DATE)
    , CAST ('2022-07-25' AS DATE)
  )
SELECT C.*
FROM
(
SELECT CALDT, LAG (CALDT) OVER (ORDER BY CALDT) AS LAG_CALDT
FROM CALNDR
) C
-- JOIN TRNHST ...

-- You must keep this expression in WHERE >>OUTSIDE<< of the subselect 
-- to get the desired result
WHERE C.CALDT = 
CAST ('2022-07-25' AS DATE)
--CAST ('2022-07-24' AS DATE)
;
```

The problem with `LAG` is that you can't use it, if you have non-continuous calendar as in your case, and `CURRENT_DATE` for some day (as `2022-07-24` in the example) doesn't exist there.

BTW, I don't know if it's some problem namely with my IBM i v7.5 or not, but if I move the `WHERE` clause to the subselect, I get wrong result of the query at all - it doesn't achieve the goal desired here and doesn't return the expected result.

**Aggregation function use**

```
WITH 
  CALNDR (CALDT) AS
  (
    VALUES
      CAST ('2022-07-21' AS DATE)
    , CAST ('2022-07-22' AS DATE)
    , CAST ('2022-07-25' AS DATE)
  )
SELECT C.*
FROM
(
SELECT MAX (CALDT) AS LAG_CALDT 
FROM CALNDR
WHERE CALDT < 
CAST ('2022-07-25' AS DATE)
--CAST ('2022-07-24' AS DATE)
) C
-- JOIN TRNHST
;
```

Works disregarding of the presence of `CURRENT_DATE` in the calendar.

Comment: Maybe `SELECT MAX (DT) DT` --> `SELECT MAX (DT) as prev_dt, DT` ?

Comment: I understood the "based on the previous calendar work date" condition as "get the last work day from the calendar which is less than CURRENT_DATE". It was some guessing of course, since there is no more precise explanation of the date selection algorithm, no data example and the result desired on it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if "prior working day" for a given date is something you need.  You should consider adding such a column to your calendar table.

While you're at it, might as well add a "next working day".

One of the biggest benefits to a calendar table is the ability to pre-calculate such columns. Thus, greatly simplifying your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Not real sure what LAG does as I have never used it. So, here's another solution using a cross join:

```
WITH calendar (workdt) AS (
    VALUES (CAST('2022-01-01' AS date)),
           (CAST('2022-02-01' AS date)),
           (CAST('2022-03-01' AS date)),
           (CAST('2022-04-01' AS date))
    ),
orders (orderno, orderdt) AS (
    VALUES (1, CAST('2022-01-15' AS date)),
           (2, CAST('2022-02-15' AS date)),
           (3, CAST('2022-03-15' AS date)),
           (4, CAST('2022-04-15' AS date))
    )
SELECT * 
FROM orders a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT max(workdt) prevdt FROM calendar WHERE workdt < a.orderdt) b
```

The cross join only returns a single row for each record in the calendar file, and that row contains the largest work date less than the order date. LATERAL just lets the sub-query access columns from the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

write an SQL function named `calndr_prevWorkDate` that returns the previous work date.

Then use that function in the `WHERE` clause of an `SQL SELECT` statement to select records from the `TRNHST` table:

```
select     a.*  
from       trnhst a                    
where      a.trandate = calndr_prevWorkDate( )
```

Here is the SQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calndr_prevWorkDate(                
startDate   date default current date )                        
RETURNS     date                                               
language sql                                                   
specific    calndrf1                                           
SET OPTION  datfmt = *ISO,   DLYPRP = *YES, DBGVIEW = *SOURCE, 
            USRPRF = *OWNER, DYNUSRPRF = *OWNER, COMMIT = *CHG 
BEGIN                                                          
                                                               
declare     vCalDate  date ;                                   
declare     vSqlCode decimal(5,0) default 0 ;                  
declare     sqlCode int default 0 ;                            
declare     sqlState char(5) default ' ' ;                     
declare     vSqlState char(5) default ' ' ;                    
declare     vErrText varchar(256) default '' ;                 
                                                               
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION                      
begin                                                          
SET     vSqlCode  = SQLCODE ;                                  
SET     vSqlState = SQLstate ;                                 
get     diagnostics exception 1 vErrText = message_text ;      
end ;                                                          
                                                               
select      a.caldate                                
into        vCalDate                                 
from        calndr a                                 
where       a.caldate < startDate                    
            and dayofweek(a.caldate) not in ( 1, 7)  
order by    a.caldate desc                           
fetch first row only ;                               
                                                     
return      vCalDate ;                               
END
```

Answer (score 0):

if all u need is the previous date from a table
you can use something like that

select *
from TRNHST
where Trans_Date =
(
select calendar_Date
from CALNDR
where calendar_Date < current date
order by calendar_Date desc
limit 1
)